# Why can't I trigger select change event using C# webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, onchange

jQuery function written as below on URL:

```
$("#letter").on("change", function() {
//some work getting done
}
```

want to access the same function from C# code behind, unable to invoke change event from C# code behind using webbrowser control in winforms application, tried below code, but not getting work:

```
HtmlElement selectletter = br.Document.GetElementById("letter");
selectletter.InvokeMember("onChange");
```

Comment: what's-with-the-kebab-case-title? :p

Comment: Not sure about C# codebehind but `.InvokeMember("onChange")` seems wrong, since you're not assigning the `onChange` property but adding an event listener. If the codebehind is even interacting with the rendered page, I'd expect to send a change event. Although I'm not even sure if there is any advantage to doing it via codebehind.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found now a code, that actually works:

```
br.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", new Object[] {"$('#letter').trigger('change');", "JavaScript" });
```

Comment: tried this also ,not working.

Comment: Is it work, if you use the `.onchange` attribute?

Comment: tried selectletter.RaiseEvent("onchange"); also , but not getting work.

Comment: I mean `document.getElementById('letter').onchange = function() {/* Something */}`, without jQuery works?

Comment: i am setting value in first dropdown, on change of first dropdown want to call on change written in third party URL js file, based on first dropdown value need to bind ajax output values in second dropdown from c# behind only  - accessing it via webbrowser control.